# Is the adverbial in the sentence in the right place?

Tags: grammaticality, word-order

> The institution name I used was "Institution name".

Is the "I used" in the right place in the sentence?

Comment: Depends what you are trying to say. Are you trying to provide the name of *the institution you used*, or *the name you used* to refer to the institution?

Comment: I was filling form with data. There was name, time, institution. Institution I set in form was "institution name". After form was send the program crash. I was sending error report with data I use. One of them was name of institution I set to form. So the secon option is true it is name I use to refer institution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is correct usage. In order to fill a particular field in a form (Institution Name), you used a particular piece of information ("Institution name").